# How to overcome libc resolver limitation of maximum 3 nameservers?

Tags: linux, debian, dns, dhcp

Suppose I work in environment with number of domain changes and slow propagation.
I want to test domain configuration immediately after setting change but the propagation is slow.
So I want to add more nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf` file in my Debian 6.0.3 laptop. Especially domain name servers of my domain name registrar.
I do it by adding:

```
append domain-name-servers 85.128.130.10, 194.204.152.34;
```

to my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file. After reconnecting to the network my `/etc/resolv.conf` is updated properly, but with following message:

```
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
```

So is there a way to use more than 3 nameservers at the time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put only `127.0.0.1` as a name server in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and run a DNS cache locally. I recommend [Dnsmasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), it's lightweight and easy to setup. On distributions such as Debian and Ubuntu, I also recommend installing the [resolvconf](http://packages.debian.org/resolvconf) package, which takes care of maintaining `/etc/resolv.conf` when you aren't running a local DNS cache, or of maintaining the DNS cache program's configuration when you are.

Comment: Yes, local DNS cache ( and specifically **dnsmasq** ) did the trick.
I'll let myself to expand Your solution below.

Comment: I'd like to add that systemd will provide [systemd-resolved.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) which is a system service that manages network name resolution. It implements a caching DNS stub resolver and an LLMNR resolver and responder.

Comment: Well, this solution will works with strict order ?

Answer (score 9):

This is how I made Debian use more than 3 nameservers at a time.

1. Install **dnsmasq** package
2. Configure my local DHCP client not to use DNS server addresses provided by DHCP server, but only local server instead. To do so I add in my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file the following line

   `supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;`
3. Configure **dnsmasq** not to use the default `/etc/resolv.conf` file, but its own alternative one. In `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` add the following line

   `resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dmasq`
4. Create `/etc/resolv.dmasq` with as many nameservers as you like.
5. Restart the `dnsmasq` service.

I tested it with 9 defined nameservers not containing my domain. The system couldn't resolve its name. When I added the 10th nameserver, the system resolved its name correctly.

Answer (score 5):

From resolv.conf:

> Up to MAXNS (currently 3) name servers may be listed, one per
>                    line.  If there are multiple servers, the resolver library
>                    queries them in the order listed.  If no nameserver entries
>                    are present, the default is to use the name server on the
>                    local machine.  (The algorithm used is to try a name server,
>                    and if the query times out, try the next, until out of name
>                    servers, then repeat trying all name servers until a maximum
>                    number of retries are performed.)
>
> Once all the nameservers are tried, and the query fails the default is
>   to return the host not found message.
>
> Can you repeat the same line below in the conf file so that multiple
>   `nameserver` directives are added. Each line of `nameserver` directive
>   supports upto 3 DNS addresses (per line).
>
> Please note that only one host is ever tried, and that is on the top
>   of the list in resolv.conf; if the address is not found on the first
>   server or the server is not reachable, and only then the second is
>   tried and then continues for the third server if the query on the
>   second server fails. There is no round-robin or random selection of
>   nameservers from resolv.conf during the host resolution, so the cost
>   of trying all the nameservers will be directly taxing on the
>   performance of underlying systems/applications.

However, I think you better implement a local caching nameserver , the increase in DNS performance for applications using/depending on the host resolution would increase if the number of dns calls are reduced/depends on the latency as well.

Another approach would be to use openDNS servers, they have perhaps the most updated and also fast serving DNS servers on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer. I am not sure if this would be relevant on Debian but this is lately more an conventional (& fashionable) approach to be found on almost all latest distribution releases.

Use Networking profiles. The idea is to switch to the network settings in a differring network environments either dynamically or use user inputs, while still maintain the copies of the configuration files and settings for all the other networks which may not be active at the time.

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/switchingnetwork.htm
http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/forums/showthread.php/15822-Configure-multiple-network-profiles
http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to test changes in DNS zones using `dig` instead of the local resolver. You can specify the DNS server to query using

$ dig @8.8.8.8 name.to.resolve

(to send the query to 8.8.8.8). This way you don't need administration control about the host you test this on and you can tune a whole lot of the query details. Also you see more details about the reply.

Answer (score -3):

Edit `/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc` the following line

```
[ "$N" = 3 ] && return 0
```

To

```
[ "$N" = 4 ] && return 0
```

You can now insert 4 nameservers in `/etc/network/interfaces`, insert the line in your interface

```
dns-nameservers x.x.x.x y.y.y.y a.a.a.a b.b.b.b
```

Comment: If libc doesn't use more than three, this change seems pointless.

Comment: This suggestion seems worse than pointless - it will hide the fact that there is a problem, but there will still be a problem.